# How to make Ioslides a solid white background?

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, ioslides

Ioslides for Rmarkdown have this gradient background, and I would like it to be solid white.

I tried two different ways to remove the gradient effect using a css file, but neither have been successful.

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}

slide {
    background-color: white;
}
```

An online demo of the problem is here:

https://rpkgarcia.shinyapps.io/NISSpresentation2022KurtzGarcia/#1

Comment: Do you have an element like `<slide>` or is it `<div class="slide">`?

Comment: honestly...I am not sure.

Comment: If you have an online demo of what you have, I can take a look

Comment: https://rpkgarcia.shinyapps.io/NISSpresentation2022KurtzGarcia/#1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient is most notable on slide 7:

[image]

You were trying to set the `background-color`, but it's actually a `background-image` that has the gradient.

If you add the following css rule

slides slide
{
background-image: none;
}

The gradient is removed:

[image]

Comment: So instead of the background being completely white, its fades to light gray. Its more obvious on slide 7

Comment: @kpr62 Please see the update